# Decomposing large bit mult or exp into smaller bit operations

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics, binary, assembly

Imagine a machine that can only hold N-bit values (N-bit uint).

The machine can also calculate the 2N-bit result of two operations: mult, exp.
The 2N-bit result is stored across 2 N-bit values (high/low bits).

How could we then code the mult (or exp) of 2 2N-bit values that would result in a 4N-bit value?
The 2 2N-bit inputs would be stored across 4 N-bit values and the 4N-bit result would be stored across 4 N-bit values as well.

Is there somewhere I can read about the kind mathematical breakdown to code this?
Needed for a real world assembly coding.

thx

Comment: Yuval Filmus's answer gives you the idea for this.  You can also look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm for further details.  Also, you may want to check out the related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

For product, here is the idea:
$$(2^NA + B)(2^NC + D) = 2^{2N}AC + 2^N(AD+BC) + BD.$$
Exponentiation isn't a primitive operation in integer arithmetic.